# Sending welcome message in channel using discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I started to write a discord bot using discord.js. I also followed the guid they provided until I was finished with "Event handling": https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/event-handling.html#reading-event-files

I wrote my first event where I want the bot to write a welcome message in a channel when somebody joins the server.
This is my code:

welcome.js

```
const { Events } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: Events.GuildMemberAdd,
    once: true,
    execute(client, member) {
        const channelID = '1194723491551912079';
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelID);
        const message = `Welcome <@${member}>!`;
        channel.send(message);
    },
};
```

The slash commands from the guide (user, ping and server) are working and also the ClientReady event. I don't know what to do after searching for some solutions and being new to js.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Edit: my index.js as well:

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.commands = new Collection();
const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

// command handling
for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        } else {
            console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}

// event handling
const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}

client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just make use of the "guildMemberAdd" event.

```js
// I'll assume you've already imported the Client class and defined it

client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
   let channelId; // Add your desired channel Id here
   let channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(channelId);
   let message = `Welcome <@${member.id}>`;

   await channel.send(message);
   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have **handlers** for **events**, you need to create a file for the **`guildMemberAdd`** event in the **events folder** and write all the functionality inside.

Example file **`onGuildMemberAdd.js`**

```js
const { Events } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: Events.GuildMemberAdd,
  async execute(member) {
    const welcomeChannel = await member.guild.channels.cache.get('YOUR CHANNEL ID HERE');

    await welcomeChannel.send({
      content: `Welcome <@${member.id}>`
    })
  },
};
```